# WPF Converter in DataGridCell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create converter that shows me if something got value is Other then "None" just write X in cell so I have created simple element style:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource SetBitConverter}}"/>
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

And converter is as well simple

```
public class SetBitConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = value as string;

        switch (input)
        {
            case "None":
                return "OK";
            default:
                return "X";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Now problem is that on value set it will not enter converter, although if i change property from Text to Background for example, it will enter converter with no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value applied by a Style will always be of lower priority than one that has been set directly or, as in your case, by a Binding. If you want to add a Converter, add it to the `Binding` property of the `DataGridTextColumn` or use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead.

E.g.:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource SetBitConverter}}"/>
```

Here is a comparison of the auto-generated default column and the one from above:

[image: Comparison]

---

> **Why does dependency property precedence exist?**
>   Typically, you would not want styles to always apply and to obscure even a locally set value of an individual element (otherwise, it would be very difficult to use either styles or elements in general). Therefore, the values that come from styles operate at a lower precedent than a locally set value.

[Technical Background on Value Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence)

1. Property system coercion
2. Active animations, or animations with a Hold behavior
3. **Local value**
4. TemplatedParent template properties
5. Implicit style
6. Style triggers
7. Template triggers
8. **Style setters**
9. Default (theme) style
10. Inheritance
11. Default value from dependency property metadata